# Finding the largest power of 10 that divides evenly into a list of numbers

Tags: python, math

I'm trying to scale down a set of numbers to feed into a DP subset-sum algorithm. (It blows up if the numbers are too large.) Specifically, I need to find the largest power of 10 I can divide into the numbers without losing precision. I have a working routine but since it will run often in a loop, I'm hoping there's a faster way than the brute force method I came up with. My numbers happen to be Decimals.

```
from decimal import Decimal
import math

def largest_common_power_of_10(numbers: list[Decimal]) -> int:
    """
    Determine the largest power of 10 in list of numbers that will divide into all numbers
    without losing a significant digit left of the decimal point
    """
    min_exponent = float('inf')
    for num in numbers:
        if num != 0:
            # Count the number of trailing zeros in the number
            exponent = 0
            while num % 10 == 0:
                num //= 10
                exponent += 1
            min_exponent = min(min_exponent, exponent)

    # The largest power of 10 is 10 raised to the min_exponent
    return int(min_exponent)


decimal_numbers = [Decimal("1234"), Decimal("5000"), Decimal("200")]
result = largest_common_power_of_10(decimal_numbers)
assert(result == 0)
decimal_numbers = [Decimal(470_363_000.0000), Decimal(143_539_000.0000), Decimal(1_200_000.0000)]
result = largest_common_power_of_10(decimal_numbers)
assert(result == 3)
divisor = 10**result
# Later processing can use scaled_list
scaled_list = [x/divisor for x in decimal_numbers]
assert(scaled_list == [Decimal('470363'), Decimal('143539'), Decimal('1200')])
reconstituted_list = [x * divisor for x in scaled_list]
assert(reconstituted_list == decimal_numbers)
```

Comment: I have no idea what *"divide into the numbers without losing precision"* means. An example would be good.

Comment: Are your numbers always integers?

Comment: @Kelly Bundy, I provided 2 examples. To explain another way, I want to wind up with numbers without decimals that can all be reconstructed by multiplying by 10**result. As for the input, yes, in my case the numbers will always be whole numbers, although that shouldn't be required, since the result will = 0 if any number in the list has a decimal part.

Comment: Ah. I'd still suggest showing examples *above* the code, not only embed them. Code posted here is frequently wrong, even when their authors say it's correct, so I don't read code until I know what the task is. Returning 0 for numbers with decimal parts seems wrong, I'd expect negative powers, for example for input number 3.14 I'd expect result -2. But of course it's your question, your rules :-)

Comment: Hmm, I'm curious: If you only have whole numbers, why are you using Decimal?

Comment: Decimal is what's coming out of a MySql query. But your point is taken - I've since modified the load routine to change the Decimals to int. Runs faster and less subsequent fooling around in the code.

Comment: Hmm... another thought: you said this is for DP subset-sum. And you divide all values by the greatest power of 10 that divides all of them, right? Wouldn't it be even better if you divided all values by their greatest common divisor? For example, you turn [140, 210] into [14, 21]. Why not into [2, 3]?

Comment: With the number of items in my typical list (8-30) a) I don't know how often I'd see additional gcds beyond 10. The odds of that many numbers even all being even is low, let alone higher gcds. b) I don't think I'd see that much improvement in the subset-sum speed. But I am just guessing and this is an interesting idea to try out.

Comment: It would also make the solutions of the answers simpler which start by computing the GCD. You wouldn't have to do anything after that, could just use that.

Comment: I now realize I'm an idiot. Of course I can just use the GCD, no matter what it is. Subset-sum will provide the same result if all the terms and total are divided by GCD. In my case GCD will usually wind up being a power of 10 but that doesn't matter. And a simple GCD is much faster.

Comment: Just like I thought :-). Included it in the benchmark that I added to my answer now. One more thing, out of curiosity: Is the runtime for this actually significant? I'd imagine it's insignificant compared to the subset-sum algorithm you're then running on the divided numbers.

Comment: It was significant when I was using my brute force function :-)

Comment: Quite surprising. I'd think the subset sum algorithm does **much** more work. What percentage of the total time was for this computation of the power of 10?

Comment: I'm using subsetsum coded in c++ from https://github.com/trevphil/subsetsum. It's pretty fast with my data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done all at once with the math library if your list is all integers.

```
import math

def largest_common_power_of_10(numbers):
    
    # get the greatest power of 10 that divides all numbers in list
    gcd_nums = math.gcd(*numbers)
    gcd = [x for x in range(1, len(str(gcd_nums))) if gcd_nums % math.pow(10, x) == 0]

    if len(gcd) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        gcp = max(gcd)
        return gcp
```

Examples:

```
numbers = [11230000,125,44500000]
largest_common_power_of_10(numbers)
# 0

numbers = [11230000,1540,44500000]
largest_common_power_of_10(numbers)
# 1

numbers = [11230000,1540000,44500000]
largest_common_power_of_10(numbers)
# 4
```

Note:

This may only work with python 3.9 and greater because math.gcd() starrted accepting lists in that release.

Comment: Correction has been made and examples covering cases have been posted along with output.

Comment: @JesseSealand, wow, that's about 4 times faster. Nice one!

Comment: @MikeP I've been wondering about the speed. What are you using to measure? The examples from your question? I very often write benchmarks comparing solutions, but here it's not clear how your actual data typically looks like, i.e., how many integers you have and how many trailing zeros they tend to have. Ideally you'd provide benchmark code or a generator for realistic data.

Comment: I just used timeit.timer() and ran a loop 1,000,000 times with the same typical data I see. Speaking of which, the source data is financial data. Typically the numbers are in the range 1,000,000 to 100,000,000,000, but with the least significant 3 or 6 places usually zeroes (but occasionally 0 or 4 or 5 places, whatever). Right of the decimal point is always zeroes. Hence the ability to do this scaling work to reduce the size of the numbers. The number of items in the list will generally range from about 8 to 30.

Comment: @MikeP How frequently do numbers have 0 least significant places being zero? Last missing piece for the benchmark I'm writing.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`math.gcd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.gcd) to get the greatest common divisor of the given numbers, and then use [`decimal.Decimal.normalize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.normalize) to align the GCD with an exponent that would leave no zero on the right of its significant digits. That exponent would be the power of 10 you're looking for:

```
import math
from decimal import Decimal

def largest_common_power_of_10(numbers):
    return Decimal(math.gcd(*numbers)).normalize().as_tuple().exponent
```

so that:

```
print(largest_common_power_of_10([1234, 5000, 200]))
print(largest_common_power_of_10([470_363_000, 143_539_000, 1_200_000]))
print(largest_common_power_of_10([11_230_000, 1_540_000, 44_500_000]))
```

outputs:

```
0
3
4
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/OBvYR2

[Benchmark](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZVRLbtswEF11o1NMUQQmXUWR26YoDLirrgoUCFB05RoCYw1tIhIliHTiNMhJusmm3fcKPUZP0xlS8i9cWCbffN8b8ufv9t6vG_v09Gvj9fmHfy--mbptOg-18utEd00NJS5NrSrogU9xmyQlavhibvBK2E19jZ2bQmWcn_cGCwnnH8FYP02AVm1sgdu2sWg9zEBXjfJiZKweyYDrpgOKQw4whAvnvIwO0MsZ5PtDXgcB8yPgbm0qDE5nMMlh9syTF8MXFzMyeAbtAr8m-Ag96YO24vAo3bnGtjr0m84yDUdmMtL3GZ3Dr6gqZcuBRRkLDT-vYIUe_Bph1aHy6Dy0zR120Ghuy6-Vh9LcmhIdqKoamGMSWYoQY7UsCzp3XCxpmtFejIdcgwWB823QYMvOnbIrFJMUKrTC-U4MQaSUrMYu5lmMSUWJSZ7CVgaqF0nSy8b-ZCxPFOhZibxj5XAPrZZtqHQb_E49CI3MXVdrZ-zqhLTeqp9A8bxfmdmmI8j8QCEz5Qq_aSv-OwiTJHpjl0xWGO30SKJ0SJvEm0E0lfTpLwbvAnER9KZG4wcw7lK6TFptKl_wvgPlAtBFD-eVJ9UMpR8uISqbgo4f50u8TXrE3TsigmXbpSUFcgljHozxGE6OWVpzIG1OS5JOnJ67fdBTmC-CmWazwMJjoJrLckL3FHu2nnvOg2-DvWd7R0VhKUK4uV7I-fRysTjURI8euA3hSav32Rv9CH__wEPoKZy9C2c0UqOEgxb7Wi_zPvVxcfuR8XTBI49iPzBaHEzPUFam2hZtLJOM4Zx8ZbKL2zcRwqdwg_ez0Hufvu34Fg9skCxZUVhVY1HQbY7g6Lu9Cu_pdJSyRNktDZ1prIyva__IDo_tfw) (test code borrowed from @KellyBundy):

```
  0.11 ± 0.01 ms  blhsing
  0.15 ± 0.00 ms  JesseSealand
 85.91 ± 0.50 ms  MikeP
```

Comment: Now the question is: How realistic is your benchmark test case? :-) The OP commented that Jesse's is about 4 times faster than theirs(?) (in however they measured, unknown...). [Faster solution](https://ideone.com/t1xKm1) taking advantage of your test case "shape". And yours and Jesse's are usually about equally fast, you two spend 99% of your time in `math.gcd` (and only about 0.001 ms in post-processing).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working with a list of `Decimal` objects, you can avoid having to do a round-trip conversion from `Decimal` to `int` and back again to `Decimal` to perform arithmetic on the numbers. All that is required is to [`normalize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) each of the `Decimal` objects and then take the minimum exponent in the normalized input sequence. This is an object-oriented solution to the problem.

```py
def largest_common_power_of_10(numbers: list[Decimal]) -> int:
    return max(0, min(d.normalize().as_tuple().exponent for d in numbers))
```

Using the `gcd` approach by @Jesse Sealand, or @blhsing seems to be the fastest algorithm when using smaller numbers, or numbers that you would expect to fit into the word size of a standard computer. However, If you are dealing with very large numbers, then it appears to be considerably faster to use the object-oriented approach.

`Decimal` objects represent numbers internally as strings. The `normalize` method simply follows pointers in the string until it finds a non-zero character. On the other hand, arithmetic of very large numbers is slow relative to small numbers, since the very large numbers cannot fit into the word size, and so arithmetic is done in software instead of hardware.

All things considered, I would suggest using the `gcd` approach if your numbers are small, and then fall-back to using the object-oriented approach when you are dealing with very large numbers.

Update:

Here is an alternate implementation of the `gcd` approach. This version converts the `gcd` value to a string, and iterates over it from right to left until it finds the first non-zero.

```py
def min_greatest_power_10_2(numbers: list[Decimal]):
    gcd = str(math.gcd(*[int(num) for num in numbers]))
    n = len(gcd)
    i = n - 1
    while gcd[i] == '0':
        i -= 1
    return n - i - 1
```

Comment: "strings" and "characters" sounds misleading, as if they internally used text strings like `"12300.00"`. I don't think that's the case. More likely they use something like "digits" in base 10^9.

Comment: @KellyBundy I could have been more specific. In the CPython Python implementation, the "coefficient" as it is called is actually stored as a string. My understanding, is the `Decimal` number is constructed from the coefficient multiplied by the radix raised to the exponent. The `normalize` method in the `Decimal` class iterates over the characters in the coefficient string from right to left until it finds a non-zero.

Comment: Ah, the Python implementation. Yes, maybe there. If I remember correctly, that's never used (at least not in CPython).

Comment: Yeah, it's even just a wrapper around libmpdec, whose source code I never looked into. But its [readme](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/main/Modules/_decimal/libmpdec) mentions *"Core arithmetic in base 10\*\*9 or 10\*\*19"*, so I think that's its internal representation.

Comment: For your update: you could use `gcd = str(math.gcd(*map(int, numbers)))` and `return len(gcd) - len(gcd.rstrip('0'))` (no idea about speed, also depends on the data, i.e., how many loop iterations you need).

Comment: I  tracked the function down in `mpdecimal.c`, the function is called `mpd_trail_zeros`, which "Return[s] number of trailing zeros".  The internal representation of the "coefficient" is a list or dynamic array, and the function traverses the words in the array until it finds a the first non-zero word. It then counts the number of zeros in that word. So conceptually, it is very similar to the implementation in Python.

Answer (score 0):

This tests all numbers only up to the resulting power. ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rVTBjtMwEL1w8leMglCbwkLSdBdYqZz2yJHbKrJMMmktJXZkO7R8C5e9wEfxNYyTOJt00Z7WUtXMjOf5veeRf_1pf7qjVg8PvztXXX36-2pbGd1AiYVsRA2yabVxcDeEbAwb4Y6MlVhBLcwBreOFbhqteKtPaLiueJqsVdd8R2NvoZbW3Y8IeQxXX0Aqd8uAVhRF_f8dOjSNVAjuiAEUejTQFaQJtfQ4PhqBaatwcJJ1DaX8IUv0sBoExeOOHvokSV_noNZWqgMIsPKgZCULoRw1HiSVsOqB_dlBeKsJbcERz61WSE17SPqEwrMbFFMqHXKno6wRvpkOB4F-Vdp4Rl5C8GSq-SV7SfBmBrjc4JdB1xk1kZjqE6u3xGHKzqhtem5s1MWDeXsIV7KO0m22i-J3MCWukyRZJLY-zplB29XegGeu_eKgmAlr0bh16CX34ufY7D4mPLvJOFF4T79kRiPdZfw6-_zfEieKj4WXopoRVZotq4cr3myGEnsNXwVNLLRGF2j7waJ5gs4i2ELUWHI_rGz27SWePwQwPxJnPxAXFPJAYdE5c2dF9pA7q5n0FdlCrixT5MYqzmOyodDKOuk6NycCG3hCZXZk_ujE0_b9Jel4eDrGFyS8JP8A))

```py
def largest_common_power_of_10(numbers: list[Decimal]) -> int:
    exponent = 0
    next_power = 10
    while True:
        for num in numbers:
            if num % next_power:
                return exponent
        exponent += 1
        next_power *= 10
```

Benchmark:

```
  1.43 ± 0.01 μs  GCD
  1.99 ± 0.01 μs  Kelly   <= my above solution
  2.37 ± 0.01 μs  blhsing
  2.45 ± 0.02 μs  JesseSealand
 13.57 ± 0.09 μs  MikeP

Python: 3.11.4 (main, Sep  9 2023, 15:09:21) [GCC 13.2.1 20230801]
```

`GCD` just computes the greatest common divisor of the numbers. Included since as discussed ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77153903/finding-the-largest-power-of-10-that-divides-evenly-into-a-list-of-numbers?noredirect=1#comment136027128_77153903) and the following comments), that actually works for you as well (or even better).

I modeled my test cases after your [description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77153903/finding-the-largest-power-of-10-that-divides-evenly-into-a-list-of-numbers?noredirect=1#comment136027111_77154109):

> Typically the numbers are in the range 1,000,000 to 100,000,000,000, but with the least significant 3 or 6 places usually zeroes (but occasionally 0 or 4 or 5 places, whatever). [...] The number of items in the list will generally range from about 8 to 30.

So I generate test data like this:

```
zeros_pool = [3, 6] * 10 + [0, 4, 5]
def random_test():
    return [
        value - value % 10**zeros
        for _ in range(randint(8, 30))
        for value in [randint(1_000_000, 100_000_000_000)]
        for zeros in [choice(zeros_pool)]
    ]
```

Benchmark script, adapted from [blhsing's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77154427/12671057) ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fVbBjts2EL0W-ooJgoVJR-uVs9lFYMC5JECBFgUCpDdXEBRrZBORKYGkN95d5Et6aC7tvfee-gH9gH5NZkjKtuxFBNgSOTOPM28eKf3-V3fv1q3--vXPrasvX___wx9q07XGwaZ066Q27QYqXKpN2UA0vAvDJKmwhl_UJ3wv9HbzEY2dQaOsW0SHXMLlG1DazRKga6N0gbuu1agdzKFu2tKJkdL1SHp73RogHAqAHs7P86Vqb3o2h-wwydcRYDYwfF6rBn3QBUwzmJ9F8sXmq6s5OZyZ9sAvyDywntRBQ3E8le5DQ1kG3dZopmHgJgN9P6G1-AHLptRVz6IMifq_57BCB26NsDJYOrQOuvYzGmhrLsutSweVulMVWiibpmeOSeRWeIzVsipo3nKy1NMJjcW4X6v3IONi53uw42BT6hWKaQoNamGdET2IlJK7sce8CJiUlJhmKeykpzpPktg2jidnedKByErgHRuLB9Nq2flMdz7uNIKsgbmPzdoqvTohLXpFBYrzeuVEt4ZM6gGFnJS2cNuu4ce-MQH9Z2ya-xPsM61p3LkitGOvoaC7X832qKLvKftI3RdHgOdajZXt0_y-UI9SG_vcfFU_vn33NF9P6CKpt3rJmvE7PB0oNe3ZTwNRKSMn4bAg5VR0i2fFct2qJaZ-lrZAcHFqg8r1LmGU0ilTl9vGFTw2UFpvMCHCutKRnBUl1J9OWOoU6nCzrsK7JFrsvU2SBzStJQLahoV9ncJtDmPeMS9gQTJ9lcJN7ikJ6Ra8s8SQk8WezLuy2SJcxjufJ-OxX2DQ4eKwb2K14nUK15mUA7cAQq6L3mtaZFnGv5SQs37AP5kPQv2aPjTQKg5VRs884UK4a4tBYacJTgN48hzetsbg0mnqbkJSokcOHm_KTsTGe0RyZoiaIbwweqostczuQ-qDO5s7w_XtneYQVqC-TYpClxssikDOstVO6S32p4ZuHZyFDTcUH7SkK07oQXXCL5vuF4jB8myjGX6J4Pn2CqlGUMnMfOgQq4RFyPU91jNY5DAk4YuXEIvTijquFdhwrDa8DZmyvyVpYiU83KLO5WJ2k-fHcqtHjyxmwUnfTl7WX-Dfv-HRK9vPvfJz__1jYZScdPMmi2s_1SKfE70Aw3YSQzH6Fwr5e_aGpNSe0oN7n_mk7Dqkl5WIeLQvXCbhisq9lgeRxHp9Iil8wvu5pykmGtjuiRvqIQnG0W_6vf8ymY1S3tOTOzqWVKtl-E6Jnyv9Z8s3)):

```py
import math
from decimal import Decimal

def MikeP(numbers: list[Decimal]) -> int:
    min_exponent = float('inf')
    for num in numbers:
        if num != 0:
            exponent = 0
            while num % 10 == 0:
                num //= 10
                exponent += 1
            min_exponent = min(min_exponent, exponent)
    return int(min_exponent)

def JesseSealand(numbers):
    
    # get the greatest power of 10 that divides all numbers in list
    gcd_nums = math.gcd(*numbers)
    gcd = [x for x in range(1, len(str(gcd_nums))) if gcd_nums % math.pow(10, x) == 0]

    if len(gcd) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        gcp = max(gcd)
        return gcp

def blhsing(numbers):
    return Decimal(math.gcd(*numbers)).normalize().as_tuple().exponent

def Kelly(numbers):
    exponent = 0
    next_power = 10
    while True:
        for num in numbers:
            if num % next_power:
                return exponent
        exponent += 1
        next_power *= 10

def GCD(numbers):
    return math.gcd(*numbers)

funcs = MikeP, JesseSealand, blhsing, Kelly, GCD

from random import choice, randint
from timeit import timeit, default_timer as timer
from statistics import mean, fmean, stdev
import sys

zeros_pool = [3, 6] * 10 + [0, 4, 5]
def random_test():
    return [
        value - value % 10**zeros
        for _ in range(randint(8, 30))
        for value in [randint(1_000_000, 100_000_000_000)]
        for zeros in [choice(zeros_pool)]
    ]
tests = [random_test() for _ in range(1000)]

# Correctness
expect = [*map(MikeP, tests)]
for f in funcs:
    results = [*map(f, tests)]
    print(results == expect, f.__name__)
    continue
    if not results == expect:
        for t, e, r in zip(tests, expect, results):
            if r != e:
                print(t, e, r)

# Speed
times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
def stats(f):
    ts = [t * 1e6 for t in sorted(times[f])[:5]]
    return f'{mean(ts):6.2f} ± {stdev(ts):4.2f} μs '
for _ in range(50):
    for f in funcs:
        t0 = timer()
        for test in tests:
            f(test)
        times[f].append((timer() - t0) / 1e3)
for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
    print(stats(f), f.__name__)

print('\nPython:', sys.version)
```